# Finding the explicit formula of a given recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

This is the recurrence relation: $a_n=2a_{n-1}+2n, a_2=2$.The way we have found the explicit formulas in my course in the past was to notice some pattern either by finding several values or using the next terms to define $a_n$.However, I'm completely lost on the equation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following manipulations yield a homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients:

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+2n$$

$$a_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}+2(n-1)$$

$$a_n-a_{n-1}=2a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+2$$

$$a_n=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+2$$

$$a_{n-1}=3a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}+2$$

$$a_n-a_{n-1}=3a_{n-1}-5a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3}$$

$$a_n=4a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This technique is in fact quite general. It works whenever the RHS is itself a solution of an homogeneous equation, it amounts to multiply both sides of the equation by an operator that nullifies the RHS.

Comment: From equation $a_n=4a_{n-1}-5a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}$ I find the characteristic polynomial $r^3-4r^2-5r^-2=0$,then I find the roots,after that I write $a_n=\alpha (x_1^n)+ \alpha (x_2^n)+ \alpha(x_3^n)$ and find the value of all 3 $\alpha$ -s right?

Comment: Basically right, though you may find a repeated root here

Answer (score 2):

This is a linear difference equation with constant coefficients. You can get the solution as follows

1. Find the general solution of the homogeneous equation $a_n = 2a_{n-1}$, which yields $a_n^h = k 2^n$.
2. Find a particular solution to the equation: Try something similar to $2n$, say $a_n^* = \alpha n +\beta$. replacing into the equation you get $a_n^* = -2n-4$
3. The general solution is $a_n =a_n^h + a_n^* = k 2^n -2n -4$.
4. Using the initial condition you compute $k$, to get the particular solution
   $$
   a_n = 5\cdot 2^{n-1}-2n-4
   $$

Comment: Did you mean $5\cdot2^{n-1}$ where you typed $5a^{n-1}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, i'll edit.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Can you clarify what $a_n^*$ means?I haven't seen that notation used in my course papers.

Comment: @Tabris No special meaning... It is just to distinguish it form $a_n$. The point is that it is a particular solution of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$A_n=2A_{n-1}+2n$$
The solution of $A_n=2A_{n-1}$ is $A_n= C~~ 2^n$
Next, for $A_n-2A_{n-1}=2n$ take $A_n=pn+q$, we get
$(pn+q)-2[p(n-1)+q]=2n \implies p=-2, q=-4.$
The total solution is $A_n=2^nC-2n-4$. $A_2=2$ gives $C=5/2.$
WE finally get $A_n=5~. 2^{n-1}-2n-4.$

Comment: Thank you for contribution.Can you explain what does $C2^n$ mean?

Comment: @Tabris I have written it well now here $C$ multiplies $2^n$. $2$ is like common factor of a GP.